# Possibly corrupt gluon download - message "graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final” is damaged and can’t be opened

Tags: gluon-mobile

This might just be me doing something stupid but I'm getting a popup message on running `java --version` when I use the install: `graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final`

```
"graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final” is damaged and can’t be opened
```

Does anyone else have the same issue?  I've switched to my Pentium MacMini, so it's not urgent; but I do need Java11 and not 17 due to a dependency issue.

The following versions all run correctly and were installed using the same procedure and I have set the necessary quarantine paths.

```
graalvm-ce-java11-22.3.1
graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final
graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final
openjdk11-openj9
graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final
```

So it's only the `...-java11-...-m1...tar` that gives the message.

I looked for an older m1 release, but 22.1.0.1 was the only one I could see.

Comment: The [download](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases/download/gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.tar.gz) works fine for me. Just in case, you need to run `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/graalvm` before using it outside the GluonFX plugin.

Comment: Thanks @JoséPereda the quarantine command was correct, but what was curious about it is that I already had the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` path added to my quarantine and that worked with other JVMs that I installed, but not this particular one.  I had to add this one explicitly.  Please feel free to post your answer and I will accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GraalVM build [graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final](https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases/download/gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.tar.gz) downloaded from https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases works just fine.

When you use the GluonFX plugin, the first time you run `mvn gluonfx:build` you get prompted to add a password, just to remove the quarantine from it.

But if you want to run anything like `/path/to/graalvm/bin/java -version` before that, the folder is still under quarantine, that won't work, and you will get the error that you posted:

```
"graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-m1-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final” is damaged and can’t be opened
```

You just need to remove the quarantine yourself, running:

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/graalvm
```

See the open issue https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1724 for reference.